# Heap Buffer Overflow trying to reallocate memory. C Language

Tags: c, stack, stack-overflow, heap-memory

I've been writing codes for Min Stack on LeetCode. 
Problem I'm having is when I try to reallocate memory(on push method), it tells me "Address Sanitizer: Heap Buffer Overflow."

What's causing this and how can I fix the issue? Thank you

Also, what would be a better way to solve this problem?

```
typedef struct {

    int top;
    int *arr;
    int min;
    int size;
} MinStack;

/** initialize your data structure here. */

MinStack* minStackCreate() {
    MinStack* stack = (MinStack*)malloc(sizeof(MinStack));
    stack->size = 10;
    stack->top = -1;
    stack->min = INT_MAX;
    stack->arr = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*(stack->size));
    return stack;
}

void minStackPush(MinStack* obj, int x) {
    //if top+1 is equal to the size of the stack(when stack is full), 
    //I want to multiply the size by 2
    //so more numbers can fit in the stack. 

    if(obj->top+1 == obj->size){
        obj->size = obj->size*2; // this line seems to give me issues. 
        obj->arr = realloc(obj->arr, obj->size);
    }

        obj->arr[obj->top+1] = x;
        obj->top++;
}
```

Comment: Not sure that it's the *entire* cause of your problem, but shouldn't the `obj->arr = realloc(obj->arr, obj->size);` line be *inside* the preceding `if` block? Otherwise, you're reallocating memory **every** time you push a value.

Comment: you're right, I was trying to make it work in a different way. but this still gives me problems. If I just remove the if statement, then it works perfectly fine. but I want it to ONLY increase the size when the stack is full :/

Comment: Also this is not the right way to `realloc`. You should save the old pointer value for the failure case. And yes, the failures are not handled at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be coming from your `realloc` call, according to the man page:
`The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes`.

So you need to have `obj->arr = realloc(obj->arr, sizeof(int) * obj->size);`
Otherwise your indexing will be off.

It also seems that you're calling `realloc` on every call, rather than only when you need to increase the size of your array, I'd advise moving that call to inside your `if(obj->top+1 == obj->size)` statement.

Answer (score 3):

Insufficient/incorrect allocation.  `realloc()` needs the byte count, not just the element count.

```
// obj->arr = realloc(obj->arr, obj->size);
obj->arr = realloc(obj->arr, sizeof *(obj->arr) * obj->size);
```

---

Aside: Robust code would check the `realloc()` result before assigning to `obj->arr`.  [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60403245/heap-buffer-overflow-trying-to-reallocate-memory-c-language/60403399#comment106854395_60403245)